# Upload object to s3 using aws api gateway service proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have configured aws api gateway with post method using aws service proxy integration type, then I have configured the resource as s3 and gave bucket details as sub domain
in action type I specified PutObject finally created arn and used that,after all doing this I am able create a random folder in bucket but unable to upload a file which is json type.

Comment: Are you using PHP sdk?

Comment: no i am just using curl to upload a file from remote system,once api gateway is configured using service proxy

Answer (score 14):

1. Created a resource in the following order (root)/s3/{key}
2. select service proxy
3. select the desired region
4. select the desired aws service(s3 in my case)
5. In subdomain give bucket name
6. In path override give the parameter as {key}(because to pass the bucketname dynamically)
7. finally for api gateway service proxy we need to add the arn for detail explanation on creation of arn follow the  document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html
8. In url path parameters add "key" and mapped from as method.request.path.key
9. Then deploy

Comment: Could you please elaborate on steps 1, 6 and 8?

Comment: @Oli the steps are explained in more detail here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Comment: Thank you for this concise explanation. I cannot find Step 5 about the subdomain in the detailed instructions, and that's where I was getting hung up. Official docs seems to imply the bucket should be in the path instead of the subdomain.